# Automation on App open / close isn't triggered reliably

Tags: ios, automation, shortcut, appintents

If I setup an Automation in the Shortcuts App (custom Intent Extension triggered on specific App open), it sometimes takes up to 30 seconds until the extension is triggered or sometimes it doesn't happen at all, but seems to be buffered somewhere because I saw it happening, that the extension was triggered multiple times in a row for previous app opens, when it finally triggered.
The majority of the times it works fine within 2-5seconds, but the unreliability is a total let down.

I tried it with a demo application with the smallest amount of code possible and saw similar behaviour. So it doesn't seem to be memorybound or the intent running out of processing time.

Did anybody else ran into this problem or maybe has a solution?